# Rest-Assured java post Response getting null

Tags: java, post, rest-assured

I am trying to print out the response using below code, but I am getting error. I am new to rest-assured.
I store the data in excell and I have class call reusable where defined my jsonpath. (`public static JsonPath rawToJson(Response res)`). I am new to rest-assured.

```
{ 
    String response = res.asString();
    JsonPath x = new JsonPath(response);
    return x;
)
ExeclUtilitiesDataDriven2 d = new ExeclUtilitiesDataDriven2();
ArrayList data = d.getData("DupProject", "EnterDataTwo");

HashMap<String, Object>  Map = new HashMap<>();

Map.put("DUP_ID_REFNUM", data.get(1));
Map.put("DUP_LEX_ID",  data.get(2));
Map.put("DUP_LEX_ID_SCORE",  data.get(3));
Map.put("DUP_ID_PERSONAL",  data.get(4));
Map.put("DUP_COUNTRY_CODE",  data.get(5));
Map.put("DUP_CDE_REASON1",  data.get(6));
Map.put("DUP_PROD_CODE",  data.get(7));

RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("URL");
test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Load the url");
res = given().log().all(). 
    body(Map).
    when().
    post(Resources.insertions()). 
    then().and().assertThat().statusCode(200).
    extract().response();
JsonPath js = ReusableMethods.rawToJson(res);
String message = js.get("message");
String code = js.get("code");
test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Response Body is =>  " + message +code);
System.out.println("Response Body is =>  " + message);
```

_

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://I can't put the url due to security reason


Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Body:           {"DUP_PROD_CODE":"10","DUP_CDE_REASON1":"AA24","DUP_LEX_ID":"000000000","DUP_LEX_ID_SCORE":"100","DUP_COUNTRY_CODE":"US","DUP_ID_REFNUM":"000000000","DUP_ID_PERSONAL":"000-00-000"}
```

Here's the error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
FAILED: DupPostPLCC
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <500>.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:471)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:636)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:122)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:130)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:117)
    at DupSynF_Projects.DupSynF.SynApps_InsertRecordsMap.DupPostPLCC(SynApps_InsertRecordsMap.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: There may not be problem in your request building as it is giving 500 status code i.e. Internal Server error  which means you have to retry your request again and if it does not work that shows API is down due to some reason.
if you hit with postman then also it will return NULL response.


5xx: Server Error - The server takes responsibility for these error status codes.

Comment: But, I am able to get 200 OK when I ran the application in Postman

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please Set Headers(Content-Type=text/plain, charset=ISO-8859-1) before making post request using Rest-assured.